# Rendering a list of different component types in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I have a list of objects. Each object contains a `type` field that is used to determine the component that is needed to be rendered. For example, for `paragraph` type I would need to render a component named `Paragraph`. I have roughly a dozen of these different component types.

At the moment I loop through the list in Javascript. I create a div with a random ID and replace that with a Vue component that I create manually using `new [ComponentType]({ el: ... })`. However, this requires DOM manipulation. Is there a better way that doesn't require manual manipulation of the DOM structure? `v-for` or similar?

Comment: [v-for](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#v-for) + [v-is](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#DOM-Template-Parsing-Caveats) ?

Answer (score 5):

Yes there is a better way. Use [Dynamic Components](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Dynamic-Components).

Here's an example shown in those docs.

```
var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#example',
  data: {
    currentView: 'home'
  },
  components: {
    home: { /* ... */ },
    posts: { /* ... */ },
    archive: { /* ... */ }
  }
})    

<component v-bind:is="currentView">
  <!-- component changes when vm.currentView changes! -->
</component>
```

Comment: I'd add a quick code example here before the Stackoverflow police come through and remove your answer.